# Swift tab bar controller is not being updated

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a view which contain text views and a bar controller with two bars I want to update bar with data entered by user in text fields ... How can I access that tab bar after view has been loaded
[image]

Comment: What do mean by  'a bar controller with two bars'?  please attach the screenshot . Are you using storyboard?

Comment: I am working on STORYBOARD I want to send data from text fields to both bars

Comment: Attach screenshot of your storyboard

Comment: @Muneeba i have edited the post ... with screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your `UITabbarController` instance like following if you have set the storyboardID for that

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mytabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbar");
```

In similar manner  you can access the instance of your `UIViewController` that are part of  `UITabbarController and pass data on their instance. Or you can use notification for that purpose.

Comment: i am not getting your point i have attach the screen shot ... i have a container which have a child vitabbarcontroller with two bars ... each bar has separate controller i want to send data to those from may current view.... please help